# Foreach select define textarea value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm looking for a way to make a select option change a textarea value.

I'm using @foreach($collection as $item) for my options.

[image]

```html
<select class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
    <option value="">Choix modèle de réponse</option>
    @foreach($modeles as $modele)
    <option value="{{ $modele->id }}">{{ $modele->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<textarea class="form-control" name="texte" id="texte" required>GRDF Bonjour</textarea>
```

I already tried to search but I only found ways that doesn't work with the foreach.

Thank you

Comment: you may need to use javascript in order to do that. on change, get the selected value, then from there make you textbox value changes

Comment: There’s different ways to handle this. Either create unique IDs for both elements (your items in your collection probably have some sort of unique id, or at least an index, that could be used as a suffix to create unique values), and write JS code that accesses them via those. Or, don’t use IDs at all, and “navigate” from the select field the change event occurred on to the text area via their relation to each other in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<select class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 5px" id="myselectbox">
    <option value="">Choix modèle de réponse</option>
    @foreach($modeles as $modele)
    <option value="{{ $modele->id }}">{{ $modele->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<textarea class="form-control" name="texte" id="texte" required>GRDF Bonjour</textarea>
```

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 $(document).on('change','#myselectbox',function(){
    var value =  $(this).val();   // here is the selectbox value
    $("#texte").val(value);   // here put selectbox value in textarea

});
</script>
```

- if you have multiple times selectbox and textarea then:-

```html
@foreach($collection as $key => $item)
<select class="form-control selectbox" style="margin-bottom: 5px" id="myselectbox-{{$key}}">
    <option value="">Choix modèle de réponse</option>
    @foreach($modeles as $modele)
    <option value="{{ $modele->id }}">{{ $modele->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<textarea class="form-control" name="texte" id="texte-{{$key}}" required>GRDF Bonjour</textarea>

@endforeach
```

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 $(document).on('change','.selectbox',function(){

    var value =  $(this).val();   

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var key = id.substr(12);

    $("#texte-"+key).val(value);   

});
</script>
```

Comment: It's working, but I got have the selectbox and the textarea multiple time on the page, working with a foreach too, and I don't know if I can define an id like id="myselectbox1" for each box and textarea and make it works with jquery